# Pretty error handling for missing fields in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am encountering quite a bit of errors when scraping some pages utilizing Beautifulsoup, predominantly because some of the pages have slight differences in the HTML or actually do have missing fields.

I am looking for a clean way to handle these, but I haven't been able to find one in the docs or in another question. I am currently handling this with a try, except clause for each field as I still want to retrieve the remaining fields if one is missing.

```
try:
    address = house.find(text=re.compile('[0-9]{4}[ ]?[azAZ]{2}'))
except:
    address = "ERR No Address"
```

This results in many try except clauses, however, and I was wondering what would be a better way of dealing with this while keeping my code readable?

EDIT: In response to Kevin's answer: a function is indeed what I'm looking for, but I have an issue with the following:

With an eye on extensability, how would I make a function out of this which accepts not only the above find call, but any find call? I need to capture the following calls, for example:

```
house.find("a", class_='object-street').text)
house.find("a", class_='object-street').attrs['href']
house.find('span', title=re.compile('Number of')).text
house.find("span", title="WaitingFor").text
```

I think I'm looking for a 'wrapper', but no experience here. Any hints in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function which tries to find your text, and instead of raising an error, returns a string error message.

```
def safe_find(element, text, error_message):
    try:
        return element.find(text=re.compile(text))
    except:
        return error_message
```

Then you can use this function to retrieve possibly missing fields, without any inline try-except clauses.

```
address = safe_find(house, '[0-9]{4}[ ]?[azAZ]{2}', "ERR No Address")
```

---

Edit: you could make the function slightly more extensible, accepting any parameter that `find` could take:

```
def safe_find(element, error_message, *args, **kargs):
    try:
        return element.find(*args, **kargs)
    except:
        return error_message

safe_find(house, "ERR No Address", text=re.compile('[0-9]{4}[ ]?[azAZ]{2}'))
safe_find(house, "ERR no street", "a", class_='object-street')
safe_find(house, "ERR no street", "a", class_='object-street')
safe_find(house, "ERR no number", 'span', title=re.compile('Number of'))
safe_find(house, "ERR no WaitingFor", "span", title="WaitingFor")
```

... But you wouldn't be able to use this to access any attributes, such as `text` or `attrs['href']`.

---

Edit edit: you could create a special object that has an error message for all the attributes you might possibly want to access.

```
import collections
def safe_find(element, error_message, *args, **kargs):
    class FakeResult:
        def __init__(self, err):
            self.attrs = collections.defaultdict(lambda: err)
            self.text = err
            #todo: add other attributes here, like:
            #self.whatever = err
    try:
        return element.find(*args, **kargs)
    except:
        return FakeResult(error_message)

safe_find(house, "ERR no street", "a", class_='object-street').text
safe_find(house, "ERR no street", "a", class_='object-street').attrs['href']
safe_find(house, "ERR no number", 'span', title=re.compile('Number of')).text
safe_find(house, "ERR no WaitingFor", "span", title="WaitingFor").text
```

However, this *only* works if you're going to access the `text` or `attrs` attributes. `safe_find(house, "ERR No Address", text=re.compile('[0-9]{4}[ ]?[azAZ]{2}'))` with no `.text` or `.attrs["stuff"]` following it will give you a FakeResult instance instead of a string.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question a bit to be resolve the bigger issue I'm having. I'm basically looking for a solution that will not only work on the text=XXX call for .find.

Comment: Thanks again, is there any other way to still incorporate the .name or attrs['href']? I feel like I'd still need to do error handling inline if I'm unable to incorporate this.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not pretty. We're getting to the point where simply doing inline try-excepts everywhere might be more readable.

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I want and it gives me the possibility to extend. I agree on readability issues, but IMO readability is more important in the main module than in the functions its calls as I'll be able to clarify its workings in the docstring. Thanks a lot!